# Change code to fit strings - Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, count, group-by, cell-array

I have the following code:

```
NI1=[NI{:,1} NI{:,2} NI{:,3}];
[~,NI2]=sort(NI1(:,2));
NI1=NI1(NI2,:);
NI1((NI1(:,3) == 0),:) = [];
NI1=unique(NI1(:,1:3),'rows');
NI3= unique(NI1(:,1:2),'rows')

for mj=1:size(NI3,1)
    NI3(mj,3)=sum(NI1(:,1) == NI3(mj,1) & NI1(:,2)==NI3(mj,2));
end
```

My initial cell-array NI1 has in collumns: 1) the year; 2) a code that corresponds to a bank 3) a code that corresponds to the workers of the bank. EXAMPLE:

```
c1      c2  c3
1997    3   850
1997    3   1024
1997    3   5792
```

My output NI3 counts how many analysts (c3), for the different years (c1) are working in each bank (c2), for instance:

```
c1      c2  c3
1997    3   14
1997    7   84
1997    11  15
1998    4   1
1998    15  10
1998    3   12
1999    11  17
```

Now I am trying to apply exactly the same code, but my last column (c3) is a string so initial cell array fir_ins is the following:

```
1997    3   'ACAD'
1997    3   'ADCT'
1997    3   'ADEX'
```

I want to obtain exactly the same output as in NI3, but I have to change the code, since my last column is a string.

I am only missing the last part, this is the code I have so far.

```
ESTIMA=num2cell(I{:,6});
ANALY=num2cell(I{:,7});
YEAR = num2cell(T_ANNDAT3);
fir_ins=[YEAR ESTIMA I{:,1}];
fir_ins= sortrows(fir_ins,2);
[~, in2,~] = unique(strcat(fir_ins(:,2),fir_ins(:, 3)));
fir_ins = fir_ins(in2,:);
fir_ins= sortrows(fir_ins,[1 2]);
fir_ins2=fir_ins(:,1:2);
fir_ins2=unique(cell2mat(fir_ins2(:,1:2)),'rows');
```

This part is not working:

```
for jm=1:size(fir_ins2,1)
    fir_ins2(jm,3)=sum(cell2mat(fir_ins(:,1))) == fir_ins2(jm,1) & cell2mat(fir_ins(:,2))==cell2mat(fir_ins2(jm,2));
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform this "aggregation" more efficiently with the help of `accumarray` function. The idea is to map the first two columns (row primary keys) into subscripts (indices starting from 1), then pass those subscripts to `accumarray` to do the counting.

Below is an example to illustrate. First I start by generating some random data resembling yours:

```
% here are the columns
n = 150;
c1 = sort(randi([1997 1999], [n 1]));           % years
c2 = sort(randi([3 11], [n 1]));                % bank code
c3 = randi(5000, [n 1]);                        % employee ID as a number
c4 = cellstr(char(randi(['A' 'Z']-0, [n,4])));  % employee ID as a string

% combine records (NI)
X = [c1 c2 c3];                                 % the one with numeric worker ID
X2 = [num2cell([c1 c2]) c4]; % {c1 c3 c4}       % the one with string worker ID
```

Note that for our purposes, it doesn't matter if the workers ID column is expressed as numbers or string; we won't be using them, only the first two columns that represent the "primary keys" of the rows are used:

```
% find the unique primary keys and their subscript mapping
[years_banks,~,ind] = unique([c1 c2], 'rows');

% count occurences (as in SQL: SELECT COUNT(..) FROM .. GROUPT BY ..)
counts = accumarray(ind, 1);

% build final matrix: years, bank codes, counts
M = [years_banks counts];
```

I got the following result with my fake data:

```
>> M
M =
        1997           3          13
        1997           4          11
        1997           5          15
        1997           6          14
        1997           7           4
        1998           7          11
        1998           8          24
        1998           9          15
        1999           9           1
        1999          10          22
        1999          11          20
```

Comment: The code like this is much more efficient. Thank you